# submodule configuration in branches

Tags: git

i faced an issue while working on git branches.
In the master branch, i have a submodule with tag v2.0 included.
I branched out on to a new branch say fix, and made some changes to its artefacts and also updated the submodule to v3.0 via "git checkout v3.0". This i did a commit.
Now i switched back to master, with "git checkout master". It displays a message "M submodule" indicating that the submodule configuration is changed and shows a new change. The submodule had changed to v3.0 in the master branch also on its own.

Why does this happen. Why cant i switch between branches without automatic altering of submodule versions?

Comment: Are you sure that you committed the new version of the submodule?

Comment: the submodule is updated and commited, but externally. it is not changed from within the super-project. I just checked-out a new tag of the sub-module in the new branch, committed it and switched back to master when i see this.

Comment: What does `git status` output before switching branches? Does it display any modification to the submodule? (also try `git status -s`)

Answer (score 3):

The fix branch has submodule v3.0; the master branch has submodule v2.0.  After switching back to the master branch the submodule stays as v3.0 and thus 'git status' shows a submodule change.  When you switch branches you need to perform a 'git submodule update' - that will bring the submodule back to v2.0 (the version for master).